# Kibana UI not loading on Linux

Tags: kibana

I am running ES and Kibana 6.3.1 on Linux (RHEL 6.5, Santiago) with default configs.
ES comes up fine and I am able to hit localhost:9200 also.
Kibana server also comes up fine with following message:

```
Server running at http://localhost:5601
```

But when I try to access Kibana GUI, it keeps on loading showing Kibana logo with Loading written on its right bottom side. I am using firefox browser.
Please let me know what can be the issue?
Thanks.

Comment: Tea leaves reading?

Comment: Sorry, did not get you

Comment: Same issue is occurring on other linux machine with ES/Kibana 6.4.0 also

Comment: Did you check for browser console errors? (javascript errors, resource loading errors etc.)

Comment: It was a browser issue. I updated the firefox and it worked out. Thanks,

Comment: Please post this as an answer and eventually mark it as resolved. Or delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was browser issue. I updated the firefox and it worked fine.